# How to use Botan to verify a web3 wallet/password?

Tags: sha-3, scrypt

The [specification here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Web3-Secret-Storage-Definition) seems quite clear, but unfortunately I'm still doing something wrong...

I have this (single small c++ file) [repository](https://github.com/Phildo/web3secret/blob/master/test.cpp) which very straightforwardly follows the password/wallet verification process. However, the result of my cryptographic operations do not match with the wallet's `mac` key (the signal that the password is correct).

I have verified that `thisisatestwallet.json` (included in the repository) *does* open with the password `thisisatestwallet`, and the spec seems so simple there isn't much room for me to screw up. And yet...

If anyone could glance at that and tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it!

The output I'm currently getting is as follows:

```
pkey:           2F299FEF2CA3390C63DABA7A13BA4CE9D60B7FC1E58DAFD5E1089D32CFD7219C
ciphertext:                                                                     C6D18F78AF6E5E7CEA4AB804D8B9A5F974CCF92EA2537416B90ABEBD77C6B580
cipher input:                                   D60B7FC1E58DAFD5E1089D32CFD7219CC6D18F78AF6E5E7CEA4AB804D8B9A5F974CCF92EA2537416B90ABEBD77C6B580
keccak out:     7D31B612939A26418CAB1DF332D27B711CAACAA7A119013A01E1DB75DE508DAA
mac:            89655FD4BB9CCF9DE0D8F1A78025A8616C9416EC700CFAAFEF17E76C7C47338E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, the misunderstanding was that the spec says `SHA-3 (Keccak-256)`, which I had assumed was `SHA-3-256`, but is actually `Keccak-1600(256)`, which is part of the `SHA-3` standard. Fixed.

Comment: Yeah. SHA-3-* and SHAKE-* are slightly different.

Comment: It would be nice (and give you internet points) if you accepted this answer.

Comment: @fgrieu Accepting own answer doesn't earn points if I remember correctly.

Comment: @DannyNiu : according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) and my experience, accepting one's answer earns 2 reputation points rather then the usual 15. That's to still give an incentive to mark the question as settled, which in turn prevents it from poping up periodically, as the present one did. Also, I was using "internet points" as something more general: a virtual counter of how one is contributing to a better web.